# outdated GLSL version

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opengl

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm taking a computer graphics course in which we have a lab in shader programming. I know that my code works on a friends computer (OSX, integrated gpu, glsl version 3.3). When I run on my machine (Razer Blade 14, Nvidia GTX 765M), the terminal says it's using glsl version 1.5. All of my shader's headers read #version 330.

The following is what comes up when I run `glxinfo | grep -i opengl` from the terminal:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 765M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 346.82
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 346.82
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

This makes me think that there's simply something else thats gone haywire. Anyone have some tips as to what I could do/check?